# JavaScript Media Query with Event Listener

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, listener, media

so I am trying to accomplish swapping between a working slider (carousel) which displays on anything larger than 715px. Under 715px, an SVG file will display instead of a slider.

I can manage to have the image display at <715px, and the slider at >715px, but I can't get them to swap between one and the other when resizing the browser window.

Would I need an event listener for this?
Thank you.

```
$(function() {
  var mobileIMG = 'img/BSW-mobile.svg' 

  // checks if window is less than 715px, if so, displays mobileIMG
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 715px)").matches) {
    $('#slideshow').attr('src', mobileIMG);
  } else { // otherwise, runs carousel
    var imgs = ['img/slide1.jpg', 'img/slide2.jpg', 'img/slide3.jpg'];
    var i = 1;

    function changeSlide() {
        console.log('hello world');
        $('#slideshow').attr('src', imgs[i]);
        i++;
        if (i === 3) { i = 0; }
    }
  setInterval(changeSlide, 3000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener for the window resize event. And this function will need to run again when that happens.

You're going to need to do a little more work after that, like making sure your setInterval doesn't get set over and over and keep firing on each pixel of resize.

I also typically will add a delay of about a second to only redraw after the resizing stops. Because it will fire over and over again as you're resizing the window.